# twisted self.transport.write working inside loop

Tags: python-2.7, twisted

I have the following code for the client which sends some data to server after every 8 seconds and following is my code

```
class EchoClient(LineReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        makeByteList()
        self.transport.write(binascii.unhexlify("7777"))

        while 1:
            print "hello"
            lep = random.randint(0,4)
            print lep
            print binascii.unhexlify(sendHexBytes(lep))
            try:
                self.transport.write("Hello")
                self.transport.write(binascii.unhexlify(sendHexBytes(lep)))
            except Exception, ex1:
                print "Failed to send"
            time.sleep(8)

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        pass

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "receive:", data
```

Every statement inside while loop execute except self.transport.write. The server doesn't receive any data. Also self.transport.write outside while loop doesn't execute. In both cases no exception is raised, but if I remove  while loop the statement outside loop executes correctly. Why is this happening? Please correct me where I am making mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All methods in twisted are *asynchronous*.  All of the the methods such as `connectionMade` and `lineReceived` are happening on the same thread.  The Twisted reactor runs a loop (called an *event loop*) and it calls methods such as `connectionMade` and `lineReceived` when these events happen.

You have an infinite loop in `connectionMade`.  Once Python gets into that loop, it can never get out.  Twisted calls `connectionMade` when connection is established, and your code stays there forever.  Twisted has no opportunity to actually write the data to the transport, or receive data, it is stuck in `connectionMade`!

When you write Twisted code, the important point that you must understand is that you may not *block* on the Twisted thread.  For example, let's say I want to send a "Hello" 4 seconds after a client connects.  I might write this:

```
class EchoClient(LineReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        time.sleep(4)
        self.transport.write("Hello")
```

but this would be wrong.  What happens if 2 clients connect at the same time?  The first client will go into `connectionMade`, and my program will hang for 4 seconds until the "Hello" is sent.

The Twisted way to do this would be like this:

```
class EchoClient(LineReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        reactor.callLater(4, self.sendHello)

    def sendHello(self):
        self.transport.write("Hello")
```

Now, when Twisted enters `connectionMade`, it calls `reactor.callLater` to *schedule* an event 4 seconds in the future.  Then it exits `connectionMade` and continues doing all the other stuff it needs to do.  Until you grasp the concept of async programming you can't continue in Twisted.  I suggest you read through the [Twisted docs here](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/index.html).

Finally, an unrelated note: If you have a `LineReceiver`, you should not implement your own `dataReceived`, it will make `lineReceived` not called.  `LineReceiver` is a protocol which implements its own `dataReceived` which buffers and breaks up data into lines and calls `lineReceived` methods.